# Laravel orderby Score/Date (as score)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

was digging for quite some time, I don't have much code ... :(
I want to add a mechanism that will rank posts in my site based on the post score / creation date

So basically what I need is a query that gets **post.created_at** -(*minus*) **TIME(now)** as **VALUE***
and than order by **score/VALUE* DESC**

So far I've managed to order by time / score

`$posts = Post::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(12);`

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong with what you've done so far.  In particular - why will substracting a fixed value (i.e. now) from each created_at change what you want to do?  It shouldn't change the sort order as far as I can tell from your description.

Comment: What I have now is simple orderby which prefers score over date, I want to create a way of ranking in my site which will prefer new posts, but older posts of high rank will be seen in the front page as well. In other words, order the table by one calculation score/time(as score) = RANK

Comment: Got it - was going to suggest looking at Raw Expressions, but it looks like you've got an answer to that effect below now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DB::raw() function to create your ranking score and then, use it in your orderBy method.

```
POST::select(DB::raw('(score / (created_at -NOW())) as "ordering_value", other, columns'))->orderBy("ordering_value", "desc");
```

And I think what you want is `NOW() - created_at` to get the age of the post.

Comment: works like a charm! my only problem, which isn't related to this question is how on earth am I supposed to make this work with my eloquent relations? :(

Comment: You can add an order clause when you define your relations. Something like: return $this->hasMany('stuff')->orderBy('Foo');

Comment: I'll definitely look in to it, thank you! :) Already fixed it up with eloquent selectRaw();